# Nokogiri ignores everything after the first attribute because of backslashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Why does Nokogiri ignore everything after the first attribute because of backslashes?

I'm not really sure why it's doing this:

```
[12] pry(Template)> b
=> "<td style=\\\"color:#fff; padding:3px; font-size:11px; text-align:center;\\\">Home Improvement Agreement: Electrical Services & Standby Generators</td>"
[13] pry(Template)> Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b).to_html
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><td style='\\\"color:#fff;' padding:3px font-size:11px text-align:center>Home Improvement Agreement: Electrical Services &amp; Standby Generators</td></body></html>\n"
```

Notice how it produced bad HTML, as in everything after the color attribute in the `<td>` element. It closed out the attribute, and assigned the rest of the variables as HTML `name` tags I guess.

I'm curious if anyone knows why Nokogiri would do this, and what I can do to circumvent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking it to parse this:

```
<td style=\"color:#fff; ...\">
```

which is not valid. This is would be valid:

```
<td style="color:#fff; ...">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'<td style="color:#fff; padding:3px; font-size:11px; text-align:center;">Home Improvement Agreement: Electrical Services & Standby Generators</td>'
```

Comment: Why should the OP use this? Please explain for their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri makes it easy to tell whether there is a problem parsing the HTML or XML document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<td style=\"color:#fff; padding:3px; font-size:11px; text-align:center;\">Home Improvement Agreement: Electrical Services & Standby Generators</td>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
doc.errors
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>]
```